# Using a slider in WatchKit

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I want the user to be able to select a range of years on a WatchKit App, since there's no UIPicker in WatchKit, can I use a slider to make the user click + or - to increment the year, to be displayed on my label above? I read the documentation but still can't figure out how to implement the setNumberOfSteps method....alternatively, is there a better way to do this than a slider?

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

@IBOutlet weak var label: WKInterfaceLabel!

@IBOutlet weak var sliderOutlet: WKInterfaceSlider!

@IBAction func slider(value: Float) {
    func setNumberOfSteps(numberOfSteps: Int){
        label.setText("\(numberOfSteps)")
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this with a slider. To me there isn't probably a better alternative. You could also present a table view modally with all the possible years you want to be able to select from, but I think the slider is probably a better option if you don't have too many years to pick from. Here's a quick example of connecting a WKInterfaceSlider with a WKInterfaceLabel.

**Storyboard**

- Add a WKInterfaceSlider and WKInterfaceLabel to your interface controller
- Add the `slider` and `label` IBOutlets
- Add a `sliderValueChanged` IBAction to your InterfaceController class
- Set the properties to match the screenshots

[image: Label Settings]

[image: Slider Settings]

**Code**

```
import WatchKit

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    // MARK: - Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var label: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: WKInterfaceSlider!

    // MARK: - Interface Callback Methods

    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(value: Float) {
        let roundedValue = Int(round(value))
        self.label.setText("\(roundedValue)")
    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps shed some light.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  Completely missed that the data for the slider is inputted via the Attributes Inspector....